# KineticJS calling moveToTop() automatically after clicking over shape

Tags: javascript, drag, layer, kineticjs

I am with a little problem here but I don't know if it is a bug or a new feature since in the KineticJS change logs there is the following change:

"drag and drop operations now automatically dynamically create a temporary top layer, and place nodes there for groups and shapes to greatly improve drag and drop performance..."

I was used to use the version 4.0.0 in my test projects and I must use explicity moveToTop() when I want to move some shape to the top (I think that this is the correct way). Now (version 4.3.2) if I just click over some pic, it is automatically moved to the top against my wish. This temporary layer should be something internal, nothing visual. So is this really a bug or there is someway to turn this thing off.

Even the labs changed I think, before I think that the objects keeps the space order if you don't call the moveUp, moveToTop, etc, functions. For example in the following link there are no moveToTop() function calls, even this way if you click on the shapes, they are moved to the top.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-move-shape-to-another-container-with-kineticjs/

Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I dont think you can completely disable the layer, you can turn off moving the shapes into it. Say you have some shape like:

```
  var shape1 = new Kinetic.Rect({
      x: 100,
      y: 100,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      fill: 'blue',
      draggable: true
  });
```

you need to add one parameter to this to disable moving your shape to the temporary layer on drag: 'dragOnTop' which needs to be false, so make your shapes something like:

```
  var shape1 = new Kinetic.Rect({
      x: 100,
      y: 100,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      fill: 'blue',
      draggable: true,
      dragOnTop: false  //<-- add this line so that this shape doesn't use the drag layer.
  });
```

Comment: Oh thank you, this solution worked well here. But is this the new framework behavior or is it a bug? Searching with the attribute name that you teach me (dragOnTop) I found an issue about this problem on the github https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/251

Comment: Good question. I believe it to be just behavior. When you click (to drag) the item it creates a new layer and places it in the layer, without remembering where in the previous layer it was. So when you release click it places the item at the top of the original layer, unless you specifically tell it to remember where it originally was with an on('click') event.

Comment: This is a result of an optimization done on the code for when you have massive amounts of items on the screen. Like in the labs, if you have thousands of nodes, its more efficient to redraw one node in a temporary new layer than all nodes in the old layer.